# How can append multiple database fetches?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to append the content of multiple MYSQL DB fields so they are comma separated.

```
 $customer_email    = db_unqq($customer_row['email']);
```

But I have fields for 5 different emails. So ideally `$customer_email` will be

```
$customer_email =
(
db_unqq($customer_row['email1']);
db_unqq($customer_row['email2']);
db_unqq($customer_row['email3']);
db_unqq($customer_row['email4']);
db_unqq($customer_row['email5']);
)
```

but have a comma separating each (so they can be sent as emails)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`group_concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to do it on the server, but that's MySQL-specific behavior, and length limited to 1024 characters by default.

```
SELECT ..., GROUP_CONCAT(email)
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY userID
```

This assumes that the emails are stored in a separate table that you're joining on, however.

Comment: they are different fields of one table

Comment: Ah. In that case, `SELECT ... CONCAT(email1, ',', email2, ',', ....)` should do the trick

Comment: So the current PHP script     $customer_email = db_unqq($customer_row['email']); will serve up all the fields I have used in the CONCAT?

Comment: Yes, PHP has no concept of sql queries or sql syntax, it'll just see a single string field come out of the database that happens to contain the results of that `CONCAT()` call.

Comment: what about seperating it with commas (which is how the mail() script will recognize the multiple emails)

Comment: There's a `','` between each field in the concat call, which adds the commas. Or you can use concat_ws as  badlamma77 suggested below. That lets you specify a single separator to use on multiple fields. concat's just slightly more flexible.

Comment: So I would write    SELECT ... CONCAT(email, ',', email2, ',', email3, ',', email4, ',', email5,) in  PHP or PHPMYADMIN?

Comment: either. that's the raw SQL query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking your emails are in one table, as you said multiple fields. 
They really should be in a separate table. This would allow for Marc B's answer 
to work.  You could also use CONCAT_WS with your current schema.

```
Select CONCAT_WS(',', email1, email2, etc..)
FROM...
WHERE ...
```

I still recommend that you use a separate table gives you more flexibility allowing you to more easily handle it in your code without resorting to custom sql functions

Comment: If you can this should be changed, what happens if you need six email addresses...your schema is broken.  If you have a second table with the email addresses linked via a unique primary key.